# Is there a way to decrease the size of the object by removing "vptr"

Tags: c++, virtual, crtp, vtable, vptr

I have a code like this using CRTP and C++20:

```
template<class Derived>
class Base {
public:

    void m() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->feature();      
    }
   
    virtual constexpr void feature() = 0;
}

class BaseImpl: public Base<BaseImpl> {
     virtual constexpr void feature() final override  { // ... };
}
```

Is there a way to remove `vptr` so the object won't take 8 bytes (for x64), and instead will take only 1 byte? (since it never uses runtime polymorphism)?

In real code, the hierarchy is much more complex and it has 2 `vptr` (so it takes 16 bytes). Are there any extensions like for GCC or MSVC?

Yeah, definitely, one of the solutions is just to remove the `virtual` method. But since it has a complex hierarchy, it brings extremely ugly errors and unmaintainable code, since programmers should guess what methods must be implemented via reading unreadable template instantiation errors.

The whole goal is to achieve a Java-like hierarchy (with interfaces, override checks, etc), but with zero-cost abstraction.

I did some experiments (exploring code disassembly) and the compiler completely optimized all the virtual calls, providing zero-cost abstraction. EXCEPT it extends the object to have a `vptr` which is never used in my code.

I found something like `__declspec(novtable)` but `vptr` still takes space.
And yes, the size of the objects is extremely important to be as small as possible.

Comment: Don't use `virtual`.

Comment: To enforce interface, you might have contraints/concept in C++20, instead of `virtual` .

Comment: If you can wait for C++23, you can replace the CRTP with the new ["deducing this"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/) feature, eg: `class Base { public: template <class Self> void m(this Self&& self) { self.feature(); } }; class BaseImpl : public Base { constexpr void feature() { ... }; };`

Answer (score 8):

You're using CRTP, which uses static dispatch. There's absolutely no reason to use virtual here. If you want to ensure that the method exists with the right signature, use a `static_assert`.

```
template<class Derived>
class Base {
public:

    void m() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->feature();      
    }
    
    ~Base() {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<void,decltype(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->feature())>);
    }
};

class BaseImpl: public Base<BaseImpl> {
public:
     constexpr void feature()  {  };
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using static_assert or concepts (as for me, maybe it compiler bug, but the concept was always violated when using for Derived).

But in general, code looks ugly with all this decltype, is_same_v, static_assert, static_cast... it's hard to read, for all these check errors you need to explore the base class, or write a custom error message for each, which add even more tautology thing.


If only there were no that 8 bytes for vptr, it would the perfect solution for me.

Comment: just compare: 

 `static_assert(std::is_same_v<void,decltype(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->feature())>);`
    vs
 `virtual void feature() = 0`

Comment: @vitalii-32 The ugly `static_cast` is a completely unrelated problem, and trivially solvable via `Derived& self() {return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);}` https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/007f3a637cef9f69

Comment: And you don't need the static_assert or decltype or anything. That's merely there as a safety check https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81595fb3ca511ea8